# Is decision tree suitable for few samples?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, physics

Here I just want to do classification.

When I have few samples, for example, less than 100 ( the experiment data). Can I use decision tree or other machine learning algorithm?

And can I simulate many samples, like 10^8 samples with sample weight 10^-6. Then using decision tree?

I can always simulate as many samples as I want, but the experiment data will be few( I can not improve the experiment data number) . In this case, Is the machine learning algorithm result lead a right result?

For example, in this guide link:  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/

What's the meaning of the sample number? Is the sample number or the sample number times sample weight and class weight ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not clear what you mean by "simulating samples". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: There are two ways to get samples. One is experiment, and of course this is the "real" sample , the second way is to simulate the samples using some tools ( these tools can simulate the experiment instruments).  So we can get many simulated samples( for example, run the simulation tools again and again...) , but the experimental samples is limited by experiment condition then the experiment samples are few.

Comment: For example, experiment will produce 100 samples contains particle A and particle B( of course we don't know it is A or B, we just know the characters of the them ). And I want to distinguish particle A and B.  You can think A and B the class labels and some particle characters are the parameters.  Can I simulate 10^8 samples. For the simulated sample, I know the labels of them, the parameters of them, and using decision tree. And use this decision tree to predict the experiment sample's label?  Will this way take much error?

Comment: It is hard to say something in different subjects( in computer and physics...)  . Maybe the question can be in another way: if I use 10^8 sample to fit a decision tree, then , for any 100 samples ( pick 100 samples random) ( but the proportion of classes is same as it in the 10^8 samples)  , using this decision tree to predict the 100 samples label, how much is the error? It is clearly, for example , for 10^8 samples , the features are smooth change , but in 100 samples , the features may not distribute well.

Comment: And sorry for the second comment, This sentence ". You can think A and B the class labels and some particle characters are the parameters. " , it should be " . You can think A and B the class labels and some particle characters are the features". to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: The answer totally depends on the problem. A quick experiment with your actual data should tell you whether the method produces acceptable results. The chart you link to is "rule of thumb" to guide you in approximately the right direction, but if you already have an idea of what you want to try, you're already past that stage.

Comment: If you can't obtain more samples, though, what could you possibly want to use the resulting classifier to classify?

Comment: For a simple problem with a clear correlation between samples of the same category, 100 training samples is plenty. But then why would you want to use machine learning at all? Just hard-code smaller shoe size => younger child, or whatever your problem domain is. But more likely, your problem is just too noisy, and/or your features are too crude.

Comment: For your second question the reason is that I don't know the label of the actual samples and I want to classify them. This is in fact the thing I want to do. So I have to provide some way to classify them. So I simulate some samples ( for these samples I know the labels) , so I use this samples to fit a decision tree. To avoid statistic error, I have to simulate many samples and them the feature of them are well distribute. My worry is that if I use this result ( this decision tree ) to predict my actual samples, with few samples, will be full of error.

Comment: The reason that I use machine learning is first the simulated samples are many and second it is hard to point the features of samples in one category.

Comment: Duplicating samples to increase the size of the training set is just pointless. Again, my suggestion is try it and see what happens; but be prepared to be disappointed.